# How can I set datetimepicker to Monday with customized time?

Tags: c#

I am new to c# and I am using windows forms.

I am trying to set the `datetimepicker` to Monday (first day of the week) with a time of `10:00:00` when button is clicked. I mean regardless of which day it is I want when I click button the `datetimepicker` goes to Monday of the same week with time of `10:00:00`

For example the datetime now is `22/3/2016 11:15:00` I want to set it to the date of Monday of the same week (which is yesterday) at 10am = `21/3/2016 10:00:00`

I tried this code but it goes to `23/3/2016 10:00:00` which is tomorrow.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dateTimePicker1.Value = 
      DateTime.Today.AddDays((int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek - 1).AddHours(10);
}
```

Anyone knows hows to do that? please help, Thank you

Comment: AddDays(-1).  You have DayOfWeek which is 2 for Tuesday and subtracting 1 which is 1.  So you have AddDays(1).

Comment: @ jdweng . sorry I don't get what you mean, I already subtracted 1 from AddDays() but did not work. any idea?

Comment: Don't subtract, ADD the number -1.  AddDays(-1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do I think:

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime
                          .Today
                          .AddDays(-(DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Monday))
                          .AddHours(10);
```

[I've made a fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3vJNBE)

Note that if this is called on Sunday, it'll go to the next Monday. This is consistent with the `CultureInfo` where in most, Sunday is considered the first day of the week.

If you want to account for it using the current culture (if that culture says that first day is monday), you can do:

```
var now = DateTime.Today;
var firstDayOfWeek = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;
if (now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday && firstDayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
  now = now.AddDays(-1);
dateTimePicker1.Value = now.AddDays(-(now.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Monday))
                           .AddHours(10);
```

I can't make a fiddle out of this since `dotNetFiddle` won't allow to change the culture, and the default one has the first day of week as `Sunday`, but I've tested it locally and it works.

This all above is if your requirements are what you specified in the question:

> I want to set the monday of the week I'm in

If instead you want (which is more likely)

> I want to set today at 10:00am is today is monday, or otherwise the *previous monday* at 10:00"

Which doesn't depend on whether your week is defined as 
starting on sunday, morning, or anything), then you can do the simpler (although less performant):

```
var now = DateTime.Today;
while(now.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
  now = now.AddDays(-1);
dateTimePicker1.Value = now.AddHours(10);
```

Comment: @ Jcl , my PC calendar is set to Monday as first day of the week, is this what you mean? also what is "curDay" ? thank you

Comment: @Kate `curDay` is `now.DayOfWeek`, sorry, I was making some tests and copied and pasted without much care. I've edited. And no, the PC calendar uses a different regional rules than .NET Framework. `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek` should tell you what your current culture's first day of week is ***for .NET***

Comment: @Kate actually I was wrong, it's set as `Monday` for many cultures. I messed up when testing that. Not for `en-US` though, that is set as `Sunday`

Comment: @ Jcl . Thank you for your efforts, the biggest problem is: I can not change the PC calendar to test if this code works with all days because last week I change the PC calendar  and my program crashed and datetimepicker did not respond to anything so that is why I asked you if your code works in all days or not. so now which of your answers should I take? first or second? tnx

Comment: @Kate it all depends on the specific requirements. Do you want to account for different cultures? Do you think all weeks start on monday, independent of the user's regional settings? Do you want the previous monday no matter when the week started? If it's the latter, check my update (let's call this "method #3")... I'd bet you actually want that

Comment: so now you have 3 answers , which one is the best, for me I wanted to select the first because it is simple it worked for today but will it work on sunday? tnx

Comment: @Kate again, this is dependant on your requirements: "If a week starts on sunday, do you want to go to the previous monday, or to the next one"? If you want to go to the previous monday, then your requirements don't match what you asked in your question (and you should take #3), if you want to go to the next one, take #2

Comment: @Jcl . yes I think all weeks start on monday

Comment: So you want to go to the previous monday (or to today, if today is monday), always? Then use #3

Comment: @ Jcl , yes I always want to go to previous monday, even if today was Sunday I still want to go to previous monday because sunday is considered as last day of week , so can I take first method?

Comment: Nope, take the last one. That will always set "last monday at 10:00"

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
int origin = (int)(DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek) - 1;
if (origin < 0) origin = 6;
DateTime.Today.AddDays(-origin).AddHours(10);
```

Comment: This will only work if today is tuesday, wouldn't it? I thought the OP was asking for "this week's monday at 10:00" independently of what "today" is

Comment: @Jcl `(int)DayOfWeek.Monday` is 1, so basically it's the same as yours

Comment: @ Jcl , @Pikoh , I was going to ask you the same: will it work if today was Friday? tnx

Comment: @Kate in fact,i'm checking and it works all days except sunday. Let me have a look at it

Comment: @Kate the updated answer will (hopefully) work for all weekdays :)

Comment: @Pikoh I was trying the same, and found the same mistake at the same time :-) I've taken into account current culture's `FirstDayOfWeek` though

Comment: @jcl yes, that's why i upvoted your previous answer. `DayOfWeek.Monday` could change based upon current culture

Comment: @Pikoh nope, `DayOfWeek.Monday` is always `1`, it's just an enum, doesn't change according to culture. You need to account it by some other means. I've added that to my answer

Comment: @Jcl `FirstDayOfWeek` i meant

Answer (score 1):

My solution is

```
private static DateTime FirstDay(DateTime dateFrom)
{
   dateFrom = dateFrom.AddDays(((int)dateFrom.DayOfWeek) * -1);
   return new DateTime(dateFrom.Year, dateFrom.Month, dateFrom.Day, 10, 0, 0);
}
```